# XSLT Translation Issue

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing

I am new to XSLT and am having some difficulty figure out how to translate the following:

```
  <resource>
    <id>12345678</id>
    <attribute name="partID">12345678-222</attribute>
  </resource>
```

to:

```
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
    <Attribute IncludeInResult="false" AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id">
       <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">12345678</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute IncludeInResult="false" AttributeId="partID">
         <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">12345678</AttributeValue>
     </Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple stylesheet like this should do the trick:

#### Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Match <resource> elements -->
  <xsl:template match="resource">
    <!-- Create a new literal <Attributes> element -->
    <Attributes
      Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
      <!-- Apply the child elements of this element -->
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Attributes>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="id">
    <Attribute IncludeInResult="false"
       AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id">
      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
        <!--
        Add the value of the text node of the original <id> element.
        That is, "12345678".
        -->
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="attribute">
    <!--
    Use Attribute Value Templates to use the value of the @name attribute
    as the value of the @AttributeId attribute.

    See http://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/#attribute_value_templates
    -->
    <Attribute IncludeInResult="false" AttributeId="{@name}">
      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
        <!--
        Use the substring before the hyphen as the value of this
        <AttributeValue> element (again, "12345678", omitting the
        "-222" part)
        -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '-')"/>
      </AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I was having issues getting the value of the attribute

Comment: Follow up question - if i have multiple attributes, whats the best way to call the attribute template multiple times? i tried inserting  `code`  <xsl:template match="attribute">
 <xsl:for-each select='attribute'>
    <Attribute IncludeInResult="false" AttributeId="{@name}">
      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
 </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
`code`

but i think that i am trying to access the attributes/values in the wrong manner after that

Comment: HA nevermind, the original sample you gave worked as is! thanks again!!

Comment: Yeah, `<xsl:template match="attribute">` matches all of the `<attribute>` elements in the document. Glad I could help!

Comment: So have have a follow up question - if attributeId contains the substring "fault_code", get the value of AttributeAssignment:
INPUT:
`<AttributeAssignment AttributeId="att_obl_authorization_rule_fault_code" DataType="string" Issuer="" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment">ERROR</AttributeAssignment>`

XSLT Ive tried:
`<xsl:template match="AttributeAssignment">
 <xsl:if test="contains=('{@AttributeId}', 'fault_code')" >
  <faultcode>
  soapenv:<xsl:value-of select='.'/>
  </faultcode>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>`

Comment: @user744480: Please submit a new question.